# Can I call a function from a personal Python Scripit in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

In Python Script option inside Power BI, I would like to use:

from personal_script.py import function

In order to use some personal functions to do some data transformation inside Power BI

Is there a way of doing this?

I have tried:

```
from personal_script.py import function
```

I expect the output of being able to use my personal function collected in my personal Python Script, but I got:

```
Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 9, in <module>
  from personal_script import function
ImportError: No module named 'personal_script'
```

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-I-call-a-function-from-a-personal-Python-Scripit-in-Power-BI/m-p/813584#M391150

Comment: You'll need to post the full error

Comment: Have you tried `from personal_script import function`?

Comment: Your python script must be in the same folder as `personal_script.py`

Comment: Yes, I have tried both ways from personal_script import function, and from personal_script.py import function but neither of them works.

Comment: @JammyDodger yes you must be right, it should be a path problem, right now I have my powerbi doc and my Python Script in the same folder but it is not working. I have also tried inside Powerbi in the Python Script the following code:   `
import pandas as pd
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\path to my folder'
os.chdir(path)

from personal_script import function` and it is not working neither. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I was able to solve it by doing something like this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("folder.module", r"C:\Users\USER\PATH_TO_FILE\FILE.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
import pandas as pd
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

module.Class()

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=float)
```